# Custom JSON entity parsing in Google App Engine endpoint

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

I have to transform a very peculiar JSON payload into POJOs manually. I thought I could put the JSON string into a `String` entity:

```
@ApiMethod(
  name = "postSomething",
  path = "postSomething/{id}",
  httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
)
public void postSomething(@Named("id") Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, String data) {
  //Parse data here...
}
```

When I do that, I get an error: **MissingParameterNameException: Missing parameter name. Parameter type (class java.lang.String) is not an entity type and thus should be annotated with @Named.**

I tried to use an `@ApiTransformer` but I get a similar error.

Could you please give me an example of parsing the JSON content manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by using a `Collection`s class instead of `String` and manual parsing:

```
@ApiMethod(
  name = "postSomething",
  path = "postSomething/{id}",
  httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
)

public void postSomething(@Named("id") Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, HashMap<String,String> data) {
  //Parse each item of data here...
}
```

From this, I can parse each item inside the `data`. The values contain a hierarchy of either other collections (`List` for an array, `Map` for a JSON entity) or `String` for an actual value. So by doing this I don't need to use any other JSON parsing library such as Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that String data needs to have an @Named annotation, similar to Integer id.

Comment: @Named is only for URL parameters, and not for an "entity". I'm trying to parse the body (content) of the request.

Answer (score 0):

String is not an @Entity object so it can't be passed as a parameter (a data parameter) to the endpoints API without proper annotation (like @Name or @Nullable). Either you must remove it from the method declaration or annotate it with @Name or @Nullable.